# Jackson deserialize JSON that intermittently has an array

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm retrieving JSON back from a web service. Sometimes the property in the JSON would return as an object, and other times it's an array of the object. How can I write the Java class that I'm deserializing into to deserialize properly this property with Jackson's `ObjectMapper`? Can I do with the ObjectMapper to help with this?

**JSON with object**:

```
"results": {
  "account": {
     "expiration": "2012-11-16"
  }
}
```

**JSON with collection**

```
"results": {
  "account": [{
    "expiration": "2012-11-16"
  }]
}
```

Comment: how about sharing with us your `not-working` solution?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12450404/823393) question of mine where I had to deal with polymorphic objects. Essentially you must enhance the deserializer with your own code.

Comment: In this particular case one should not have to add custom deserializers; although IMO such non-OO JSON structure is bit bad.

Comment: @StaxMan - I bow to your superior knowledge! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mark the property as a Java array or `Collection`, and enable feature  ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature. ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
ResultOb ob = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, ResultOb.class);
```

and if a single JSON Object is encountered, it gets treated like it was a single-element JSON Array.

Comment: Doh. I looked through the java docs for jackson 1.7.9 for a config like that but didn't see any. I should always look at the latest docs. Thanks!

Comment: True, this is relatively new feature.