# Jackson deserialization of type with different objects

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have a result from a web service that returns either a boolean value or a singleton map, e.g.

Boolean result:

```
{
    id: 24428,
    rated: false
}
```

Map result:

```
{
    id: 78,
    rated: {
        value: 10
    }
}
```

Individually I can map both of these easily, but how do I do it generically?

Basically I want to map it to a class like:

```
public class Rating {
    private int id;
    private int rated;
    ...
    public void setRated(?) {
        // if value == false, set rated = -1;
        // else decode "value" as rated
    }
}
```

All of the polymorphic examples use `@JsonTypeInfo` to map based on a property in the data, but I don't have that option in this case.

---

**EDIT**
The updated section of code:

```
@JsonProperty("rated")
public void setRating(JsonNode ratedNode) {
    JsonNode valueNode = ratedNode.get("value");
    // if the node doesn't exist then it's the boolean value
    if (valueNode == null) {
        // Use a default value
        this.rating = -1;
    } else {
        // Convert the value to an integer
        this.rating = valueNode.asInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No no no. You do NOT have to write a custom deserializer. Just use "untyped" mapping first:

```
public class Response {
  public long id;
  public Object rated;
}
// OR
public class Response {
  public long id;
  public JsonNode rated;
}
Response r = mapper.readValue(source, Response.class);
```

which gives value of `Boolean` or `java.util.Map` for "rated" (with first approach); or a `JsonNode` in second case.

From that, you can either access data as is, or, perhaps more interestingly, convert to actual value:

```
if (r.rated instanceof Boolean) {
    // handle that
} else {
    ActualRated actual = mapper.convertValue(r.rated, ActualRated.class);
}
// or, if you used JsonNode, use "mapper.treeToValue(ActualRated.class)
```

There are other kinds of approaches too -- using creator "ActualRated(boolean)", to let instance constructed either from POJO, *or* from scalar. But I think above should work.

Comment: I swear I had tried this method before! I updated the my question with the final solution. Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to write your own deserializer. It could look like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class RatingJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Rating> {

    @Override
    public Rating deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String, Object> map = jp.readValueAs(Map.class);

        Rating rating = new Rating();
        rating.setId(getInt(map, "id"));
        rating.setRated(getRated(map));

        return rating;
    }

    private int getInt(Map<String, Object> map, String propertyName) {
        Object object = map.get(propertyName);

        if (object instanceof Number) {
            return ((Number) object).intValue();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private int getRated(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Object object = map.get("rated");
        if (object instanceof Boolean) {
            if (((Boolean) object).booleanValue()) {
                return 0; // or throw exception
            }

            return -1;
        }

        if (object instanceof Map) {
            return getInt(((Map<String, Object>) object), "value");
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now you have to tell Jackson to use this deserializer for `Rating` class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = RatingJsonDeserializer.class)
class Rating {
...
}
```

Simple usage:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(json, Rating.class));
```

Above program prints:

```
Rating [id=78, rated=10]
```

for JSON:

```
{
    "id": 78,
    "rated": {
        "value": 10
    }
}
```

and prints:

```
Rating [id=78, rated=-1]
```

for JSON:

```
{
    "id": 78,
    "rated": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, initially I did that, but StaxMan's solution is cleaner in my eyes and reduces the actual number of classes I needed

Answer (score 3):

I found a nice article on the subject: http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html

I think that the approach of parsing into object, is possibly problematic, because when you send it, you send a string. I am not sure it is an actual issue, but it sounds like some possible unexpected behavior.
example 5 and 6 show that you can use inheritance for this.

Example:

> ## Example 6: Simple Deserialization Without Type Element To Container Object With Polymorphic Collection
>
> Some real-world JSON APIs have polymorphic type members, but don't include type elements (unlike the JSON in the previous examples). Deserializing such sources into polymorphic collections is a bit more involved. Following is one relatively simple solution. (This example includes subsequent serialization of the deserialized Java structure back to input JSON, but the serialization is relatively uninteresting.)
>
> ```
> // input and output:
> //   {
> //     "animals":
> //     [
> //       {"name":"Spike","breed":"mutt","leash_color":"red"},
> //       {"name":"Fluffy","favorite_toy":"spider ring"},
> //       {"name":"Baldy","wing_span":"6 feet",
> //           "preferred_food":"wild salmon"}
> //     ]
> //   }
>
> import java.io.File;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.util.Collection;
> import java.util.HashMap;
> import java.util.Iterator;
> import java.util.Map;
> import java.util.Map.Entry;
>
> import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
> import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
> import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
> import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
> import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationContext;
> import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
> import org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer;
> import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;
> import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode;
>
> import fubar.CamelCaseNamingStrategy;
>
> public class Foo
> {
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
>   {
>     AnimalDeserializer deserializer = 
>         new AnimalDeserializer();
>     deserializer.registerAnimal("leash_color", Dog.class);
>     deserializer.registerAnimal("favorite_toy", Cat.class);
>     deserializer.registerAnimal("wing_span", Bird.class);
>     SimpleModule module =
>       new SimpleModule("PolymorphicAnimalDeserializerModule",
>           new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
>     module.addDeserializer(Animal.class, deserializer);
>     
>     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
>     mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
>         new CamelCaseNamingStrategy());
>     mapper.registerModule(module);
>
>     Zoo zoo = 
>         mapper.readValue(new File("input_6.json"), Zoo.class);
>     System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(zoo));
>   }
> }
>
> class AnimalDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Animal>
> {
>   private Map<String, Class<? extends Animal>> registry =
>       new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Animal>>();
>
>   AnimalDeserializer()
>   {
>     super(Animal.class);
>   }
>
>   void registerAnimal(String uniqueAttribute,
>       Class<? extends Animal> animalClass)
>   {
>     registry.put(uniqueAttribute, animalClass);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public Animal deserialize(
>       JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
>       throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
>   {
>     ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
>     ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jp);
>     Class<? extends Animal> animalClass = null;
>     Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> elementsIterator = 
>         root.getFields();
>     while (elementsIterator.hasNext())
>     {
>       Entry<String, JsonNode> element=elementsIterator.next();
>       String name = element.getKey();
>       if (registry.containsKey(name))
>       {
>         animalClass = registry.get(name);
>         break;
>       }
>     }
>     if (animalClass == null) return null;
>     return mapper.readValue(root, animalClass);
>   }
> }
>
> class Zoo
> {
>   public Collection<Animal> animals;
> }
>
> abstract class Animal
> {
>   public String name;
> }
>
> class Dog extends Animal
> {
>   public String breed;
>   public String leashColor;
> }
>
> class Cat extends Animal
> {
>   public String favoriteToy;
> }
>
> class Bird extends Animal
> {
>   public String wingSpan;
>   public String preferredFood;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question - [JSON POJO consumer of polymorphic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12459070/823393)

You have to write your own `deserialiser` that gets a look-in during the deserialise process and decides what to do depending on the data.

There may be other easier methods but this method worked well for me.

Comment: I can't get that solution to work for me. I get a "No content to map due to end-of-input" error at the end of the InfoDeserializer.

Comment: I did get it to work with a custom deserialiser, but StaxMan's solution was cleaner for me.