# Jackson jr custom deserializer

Tags: android, jackson, json-deserialization

I need to implement custom deserializer to correctly parse JSON to Java object. As specified in [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jr/wiki/Custom-Handlers#custom-jsonreader) I need replace default JSONReader with my custom:

```
JSON j = JSON.std.with(new MyJSONReader());
```

But there are two problems:

- JSONReader hasn't default constructor;
- no documentation how to work with JSONReader.

How to create custom deserializer in Jackson jr?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Rahim Dastar for your answer, but Jackson jr hasn't JsonDeserializer class. Because Jackson jr is reduced version of Jackson.

I make trick after read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143114/jackson-deserialization-of-type-with-different-objects).

Instead of my custom Java class I use Map. Then I customize setter method with explicit cast:

```
//private Data data; - this is desired
private Map<String, Object> data;

public void setData(Object Data) {
        if(data instanceof Map){
            this.data = (Map<String, Object>) data;
        } else {
            this.data = null;
        }
    }
```

This works but is not a solution, because I have many classes with many fields.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson-jr 2.10 added support for registering custom readers (`ValueReader`) and writers (`ValueWriter`), as per:

https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/jackson-2-10-jackson-jr-improvements-9eb5bb7b35f

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
public class IntegerBooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        Integer data = Integer.parseInt(jsonParser.readValueAs(String.class));
        return data == 1 ? true : false;
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = IntegerBooleanDeserializer.class)
    boolean force;
```

for boolean custom serializer you can use this for each object.