# How to get the nested property of a JSON response using Jackson library?

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson

I have the following JSON schema from the response of an API which can either be :

```
{
  "meta": {
      "someData": " "
  },
  "A": [
     {
       "code": 123,
       "id": "string",
       "data": {} 
     },
     {
       "code": 123,
       "id": "string",
       "data": {} 
     }
  ]
}
```

OR

```
{
  "meta": {
      "someData": " "
  },
  "B": [
     {
       "code": 123,
       "id": "string",
       "data": {} 
     },
     {
       "code": 123,
       "id": "string",
       "data": {} 
     }
  ]
}
```

How do I get obtain just the date from the list or either property `A` or property `B` ?

I expect output to be something like:

```
A[0].data = {}
A[1].data = {}
```

OR

```
B[0].data = {}
B[1].data = {}
```

And 
 I want to store the data property, which is an object with variable number of sub properties in a map.

Comment: Does this work even with they dynamic properties of the JSON response?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use jackson's object mapper. You should create a class or interface to define your json object as well. The A or B may be an issue. You might be able to create a class/interface for each.

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final CallbackRequest callbackRequest = objectMapper.readValue(json, CallbackRequest.class);
```

Also, here is an example: https://github.com/NikhilShah1647/jackson-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/journaldev/jackson/json/JacksonObjectMapperExample.java

And here is an example of deserializing a json object with possible multiple types: [Jackson deserialization of type with different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143114/jackson-deserialization-of-type-with-different-objects)

Comment: How does your piece of code solves OP's question??

Comment: What if I want to store the data property, which is an object with unknown number of sub properties in a map?