# Jackson - allow deserialization only if json field value matches class attribute value

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following classes:

```java
public abstract class Event {
    private final String eventId;

    public Event(String eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }
}

public class EventA extends Event {
    private final String type = "eventA";

    @JsonCreator
    public EventA(@JsonProperty("eventId") String eventId) {
        super(eventId);
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

public class EventB extends Event {
    private final String type = "eventB";

    @JsonCreator
    public EventB(@JsonProperty("eventId") String eventId) {
        super(eventId);
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Problem is now I can deserialize to both classes and have an `EventB` with `type=="eventA"`:

```java
EventA eventA = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
    "{\"gameProposalId\":\"foo\", \"type\": \"eventA\"}",
    EventA.class);

// This will result in EventB with type=="eventA"
EventB eventB = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
    "{\"gameProposalId\":\"foo\", \"type\": \"eventA\"}",
    EventB.class);
```

Is there a way to instead compare the value of the `type` field in the json to the default value of `type` in the class you are trying to deserialize to, and throw an exception if they don't match?

Comment: So, if type is "eventA" it can't be mapped to an EventB object, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson deserialization of type with different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143114/jackson-deserialization-of-type-with-different-objects)

Comment: @DiegoBorba right now it can, instead I'd like the second call to `readValue` in the code above to throw an exception.

Comment: @AleZalazar I think in that question the OP wants to deserialize 2 different json to the same class.

Comment: The `type` is used for something or just to check the type that you want to `readValue`?

Comment: @DiegoBorba yes I call `getType()` somewhere else in the program. Using `type` to also solve this particular problem is just something I thought could maybe be possible, but any other solution would of course be ok as well.

Comment: @diridev The referred question might be different but its proposed solutions can solve this question, or in general provides means to customize deserialization behavior as desired, which is the actual meaning of the question.

Comment: @AleZalazar okay so maybe it could work writing a deserializer for the `Event` class that instantiates the correct subclass based on `type` in the json. Then you could downcast it to the actual subclass like `EventA eventA = (EventA) mapper.readValue(jsonString, Event.class)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best solution is **customize deserialization**, this way:

###### EventDeserializer

```java
public class EventDeserializer<T extends Event> extends StdDeserializer<T> {

    public EventDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public EventDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // Node
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

        // Fields
        String eventId = node.get("gameProposalId").asText();
        String type = node.get("type").asText();

        // Automatically checks the type
        if (type.equals("eventA")) {
            return (T) new EventA(eventId);

        } else if (type.equals("eventB")) {
            return (T) new EventB(eventId);

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The `EventDeserializer` **automatically checks the type**  based on the `type` field.

For it to work, you need to change the annotations in your classes. This way:

###### Event

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = EventDeserializer.class)
public abstract class Event {
    private final String eventId;

    public Event(String eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }
}
```

The `@JsonDeserialize` annotation specify the custom deserializer class.

So now you dont need the `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` annotations:

###### EventA

```java
public class EventA extends Event {
    private final String type = "eventA";

    public EventA(String eventId) {
        super(eventId);
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

###### EventB

```java
public class EventB extends Event {
    private final String type = "eventB";

    public EventB(String eventId) {
        super(eventId);
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Now, if you try to instance a `EventB` with one JSON with `type == "eventA"`, it will throw a `java.lang.ClassCastException`:

```java
final String json = "{\"gameProposalId\":\"foo\", \"type\": \"eventA\"}";

// Instance the object normaly
EventA eventA = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, EventA.class);

// Throws: java.lang.ClassCastException: EventA cannot be cast to EventB
EventB eventB = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, EventB.class);
```

I hope it helps :)