# Polymorphic deserialisation of nested JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, jackson

I'm attempting to polymorphically deserialise objects from a nested JSON structure over which I have no control.
I've been using

```
 @JsonTypeInfo(... include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, ...)
```

and

```
@JsonTypeInfo(... include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, ...)
```

with success but I've run into the case where the POJO type that I need to deserialise to is determined by a property which is an attribute of an object at a higher level.

From the  JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY Javadoc:

"Inclusion mechanism similar to PROPERTY, except that property is included one-level higher in hierarchy"

In my case the discriminating property is one level higher than this in the hierarchy.

Is there any way of doing this , or polymorphically desersialising based upon some extraneous data (not contained in the JSON itself)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12450404/823393)?

Comment: @OldCumudgeon - Thanks for that link and sorry for the late reply. I'll look into what you've done with reading the JSON tree.  It could be doable but I was hoping that there might be some way to do this using already existing Jackson annotaions and such.