# Deserialize a polymorphic map with Jackson, where Type information is given within the string key

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

Assume a class "Json2JavaModel"

```
public class Jason2JavaModel {

    public String someAttribute;

    public Map<String, Representation> representations;

    public String getSomeAttribute() {
        return someAttribute;
    }

    public void setSomeAttribute(String someAttribute) {
        this.someAttribute = someAttribute;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "_embedded")
    public Map<String, Representation> getRepresentations() {
        return representations;
    }

    public void setRepresentations(
            Map<String, Representation> representations) {
        this.representations = representations;
    }
}
```

Where Representation is a common base interface for different JSON representations. On serialization side, there's no problem, because Jackson knows the actual Java type. But deserialization has to be done polymorphic. The type information is stored within the map key for every entry (not as canonical Class name but something unique). So it would be possible to provide a key string <-> destination class config. Is there a way to tell jackson, that it should use the map key as type definition to deserialize the entries value?

Best regards,
Marius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an `ObjectMapper`. Have a look at my answer to [JSON POJO consumer of polymorphic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12450404/823393) for an example.

Comment: Hi OldCurmudgeon and thx for the reply. I looked into your solution and it would work, if we wrapped the Map<String, Representation> into it's own class like EmbeddedRepresentationsContainer. Then we could use your approach for a customized EmbeddedRepresentationsContainerDeserializer. Alas this structure change would mean to break our current API or introduce more methods.  If by any means possible, we'd like to stick with the map and teach Jackson how to deserialize it correctly.