# Jackson Deserialize JSON property to different Java Objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I am trying to parse a JSON structure like below

```
{
   "service":{
      "id":"7ba68ee3-73fc-4d0e-9819-6f3f23b97ab3",
      "state":"new",
      "operatingState":"Unknown",
      "serviceCharacteristic":[
         {
            "name":"privateId",
            "value":[
               {
                  "number":"505013486018300"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"publicId",
            "value":[
               {
                  "serviceNumber":"34344141",
                  "accessRestriction": "true"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"serviceProviderId",
            "value":"0002"
         },
         {
            "name":"type_w",
            "value":[
               {
                  "number":"505013486018300"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"type_f",
            "value":[
               {
                  "number":"2323123",
                  "enabled": "true"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "supportingService":[
         {
            "id":"b28f4a28-4226-4976-9373-85c0bc13b440",
            "state":"active",
            "operatingState":"Unknown",
            "serviceDate":"2019-12-20T12:05:58.000Z",
            "serviceCharacteristic":[
               {
                  "name":"profile",
                  "value":"default"
               },
               {
                  "name":"type_s",
                  "value":[
                     "bar-a",
                     "bar-b"
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"type_a",
                  "value":"false"
               },
               {
                  "name":"type_b",
                  "value":"cliBlk"
               },
               {
                  "name":"type_c",
                  "value":"true"
               },
               {
                  "name":"type_d",
                  "value":"false"
               },
               {
                  "name":"call_me",
                  "value":"true"
               },
               {
                  "name":"defaultCallBackNotification",
                  "value":"false"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and after searching/reading followed the solution provided (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12459070/2082536) and wrote a custom JSON Deserializer **(StdDeserializer)**. I can get the JSON node **(value)** in the Deserializer but then 
facing issues in mapping and returning correct Java objects.

Reason for custom Deserializer is due to the different data types associated with property **(value)**. Client is sending three different types

1. List of Objects
2. List of String
3. String

So far, I have done as below

```
1. Created abstract class value

public abstract class Value {
    public Value() {
    }
}

2. Created a class to hold list of objects

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ListOfValueObjects extends Value implements Serializable
{

    public List<ValueObject> value;

    public ListOfValueObjects() {
        super();
    }

    public static class ValueObject implements Serializable
    {
        @JsonProperty("enabled")
        public String enabled;
        @JsonProperty("accessRestriction")
        public String accessRestriction;
        @JsonProperty("serviceNumber")
        public String serviceNumber;
        @JsonProperty("number")
        public String number;

        public ValueObject() {
        }

    }

}

3. Created class for list of string

    public class ValueList extends Value implements Serializable
    {
        public List<String> value;

        public ValueList() {
            super();
        }

    }
3. Created class for string value

    public class ValueString extends Value implements Serializable
    {
        public String value;

        public ValueString() {
            super();
        }

    }

4. The top class looks like 

    public class service implements Serializable
    {
        // other properties

        public List<ServiceCharacteristic> serviceCharacteristic = null;
        @JsonProperty("supportingService")
        @Valid
        public List<SupportingService> supportingService = null;
    }

    public static class ServiceCharacteristic implements Serializable
    {

        @JsonProperty("name")
        public String name;
        @Valid
        @JsonDeserialize(using = ValueDeserializer.class)
        public Value value;
    }

5. Dserializer look like ( referncing the answer given in here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12459070/2082536 )


    public class ValueDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Value> 
    {

        public ValueDeserializer() {
            super(Value.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Value deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException 
        {
            ObjectCodec codec = jsonParser.getCodec();

            // this should be the value node ???
            JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jsonParser);

            // base on node type switch to correct class 

            // and using object mapper deserialize to class

        }
    }
```

**Jackson version: 2-10.1**

Comment: I didn't find your question very clear. Could you be more explicit about what's yur input and expected output ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I want to know how to de-serialize the JSON data having a quirk property (in the above example its 'value').