# Model class for Jackson Parser to parse Uppercase properties

Tags: android, json, parsing, jackson

I have a json file which looks like this:

```
{
    "ANIMALS": {
    "TYPE": "MAMMAL",
    "COLOR": "BLACK",
    "HEIGHT": "45",

    }
}
```

But I get property not found error. If I change it to animals(lowercase). it works fine. Can anyone suggest me the model class for this sample json file which will get parsed correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should implement new naming strategy for your case:

```
class UpperCaseNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy.PropertyNamingStrategyBase {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public String translate(String arg0) {
        return arg0.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

After that, configure `ObjectMapper`

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new UpperCaseNamingStrategy());
```

See also `@JsonProperty` annotation.

- [Change field case with an ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427167/change-field-case-with-an-objectmapper)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved this issue using @JsonProperty annotation.Saw your answer after that but since you gave the right answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: Thanks! Just one question....why did you call it `LowerCaseNamingStrategy` when it is for dealing with **upper** case variables? :)

Comment: @AdamBurley, good point, I changed a name to `Upper...`. I do not know why 7 years ago I named it `Lower...`, probably because I extend `LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy` and just copied this name.

Comment: No worries! Actually I think it's fine to just extend `PropertyNamingStrategy.PropertyNamingStrategyBase`; I don't see any benefit in extending `LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy`...

Comment: @AdamBurley, fixed, thanks for these suggestions.

Comment: Me again! Just found out that as of Jackson 2.12 (Nov 2020), `PropertyNamingStrategy.PropertyNamingStrategyBase` is deprecated. Need to use `PropertyNamingStrategies.NamingBase` instead, which is basically identical - but not deprecated :)

Answer (score 13):

Building off of Deepak's answer, depending on how you have Jackson configured, you *may* need to put the `@JsonProperty` on the getters & setters instead of the property or you might get duplicate properties in the resulting JSON.

Example

```
 @JsonProperty("ANIMALS")
 private string animals;
```

Results in...`{animals:"foo",ANIMALS:"foo"}`

```
 private string animals;

 @JsonProperty("ANIMALS")
 public String getAnimals(){...}
```

Results in...`{ANIMALS:"foo"}`

Comment: you're right, after I put the annotation on the getter method, it only produce the uppercase one... thank you

Comment: Thank you so much. U saved my day

Answer (score 3):

Thanks I solved this issue using @JsonProperty annotation

```
    @JsonProperty("ANIMALS")
    private string animals;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not generating the JSON (serialisation), but you want to consume an object without having to care about the case.

You can receive Animal or AniMal :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```