# Java objects to JSON: field names

Tags: java, json

I have a pretty standard Java POJO. Let's call it Dog:

Dog.java has a series of fields. In Java, convention says field names should start with a lower case. This means I have:

- public String name;
- public String dogType;
- public String weight;

At the same time, I have a requirement on my JSON format that the JSON members (name, dogType, and weight) all be written with a capital letter at the beginning i.e. Name, DogType, and Weight.

I am using Jackson.

If I use the standard serialization code as below, I get JSON member names written exactly the same way they are in Java.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jReq);
System.out.println(json);
```

To address my problem, I have 2 options:

- either I use the Jackson annotation `@JsonProperty(value="DogType")`, or
- I use a naming strategy as described in the [API](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html).

My question is: is there a clean way of doing it?

There are quite a few questions on SO about this that explain both ways:

- [Change field case with an ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427167/change-field-case-with-an-objectmapper)
- [Model class for Jackson Parser to parse Uppercase properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683984/model-class-for-jackson-parser-to-parse-uppercase-properties)

But none go into the pros and cons.

My initial hunch is that I should go for the naming strategy. Is that a good approach or a bad one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go for the naming strategy, too. The advantage of this one is that you can always override it with the annotations, if needed.